# Android C2DM messages are lost?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, android-notifications

I'm sending notifications with android C2DM. I'm using C2dmSharp.
I'm trying to send 200 different notifications to my phone. Server-side I get an OK response with an id=[ID of sent message] (like documented [here](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#push)) so I guess my serve is doing well. But on my phone I only get a few notifications... NOT 200! Ok I know it's not a guaranteed service but it's like 90% of notifications that aren't sent. Am I doing anything wrong? Is it actually possible to send 200 messages in a row to one device?

If you know a better place to ask this, please enlighten me :)

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Redth/C2DM-Sharp/tree/master/C2dmSharp.Server) to send the notifications

Here's the code :

```
if (notificationService != null)
            {
                notificationService.Start();
                foreach (var itemToProcess in itemsToProcess)
                {
                    itemToProcess.NotificationDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    mobile.SubmitChanges();

                    string deviceToken = GetCleanDeviceToken(itemToProcess.MobileDevice.PushNotificationIdentifier);
                    var extras = new NameValueCollection();
                    extras.Add("salemessage", itemToProcess.MobileDeviceNotificationText.Text);
                    extras.Add("ismultisale", "false");
                    if (itemToProcess.SaleId.HasValue) extras.Add("saleid", itemToProcess.SaleId.Value.ToString());
                    try
                    {   
                        Thread.Sleep(200);
                        notificationService.QueueMessage(deviceToken, extras, "key");
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        //logging
                    }
                }

                notificationService.Stop();
            }
```

Comment: try this one it is very usefull [http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html
](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)

Comment: C2DM is deprecated, there is replacement Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).

Comment: Does GCM works on pre-4.1 android versions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as C2DM is deprecated, let's use GCM! For .NET servers, there's https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp